# Policies not applied for some APIs in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We have set up a API gateway in Azure (Consumption plan). Here we have multiple different APIs already in production. Recently we have been working on a new API and have added this to the gateway.

Everything seemed fine until we started noticing some wierd behavior with the new API.
Some policies were not working, and it seems that tracing also doesn't work for the particular API.
Tracing is saying that the `Ocp-Apim-Trace-Location` header is missing, even though we are testing it via the portal. One thing that I noticed was that tracing worked if the request never reached our backend.

The policies that are not working for us is: `set-header`, `cache-store` and `cache-lookup`.
So nothing is saved to our external redis, and we are unable to set any response headers.

This is working for all other APIs in the gateway, and it also works for the new API in our dev/test instance.

I have tried creating a new API & imported our OpenAPI spec, which didnt do anything and I have not found anything online related to our problem.

Any help is appreciated!

**Policy**.

```
<policies>
<inbound>
    <!--base: Begin Api scope-->
    <!--base: Begin Product scope-->
    <!--base: Begin Global scope-->
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized.  Access token is missing or invalid." output-token-variable-name="jwt">
        <openid-config url="https://<url-to-openid-config>" />
        <audiences>
            <audience>apim</audience>
        </audiences>
    </validate-jwt>
    <!--base: End Global scope-->
    <!--base: End Product scope-->
    <set-query-parameter name="apiKey" exists-action="override">
        <value>{{key}}</value>
    </set-query-parameter>
    <!--base: End Api scope-->
    <cache-lookup vary-by-developer="false" vary-by-developer-groups="false" allow-private-response-caching="true" downstream-caching-type="none">
        <vary-by-header>Accept</vary-by-header>
        <vary-by-header>Accept-Charset</vary-by-header>
    </cache-lookup>
</inbound>
<backend>
    <!--base: Begin Api scope-->
    <!--base: Begin Product scope-->
    <!--base: Begin Global scope-->
    <forward-request timeout="60" />
    <!--base: End Global scope-->
    <!--base: End Product scope-->
    <!--base: End Api scope-->
</backend>
<outbound>
    <cache-store duration="20" />
    <set-header ="headerName" exists-action="override">
         <value>value</value>
    </set-header>
</outbound>
<on-error />
```

Comment: Would be really hard to help here without being able to look into your service data. If you're not comfortable sharing service name or some part of request that would allow me to identify your service, please open a service request with Microsoft. One thing you should check is that you backend does not return redirect status code.

Comment: Yeah, I was mostly hoping somebody had experienced something similar to this. I'm not able to share the service name, but the request returns a 200 OK.

Comment: Some part of URI that you call might also help me identify you as well. Otherwise, please open support ticket with API Management.